# Symfony2 anonymous and authenticated on same route

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.1

I would have liked in Symfony2 "v2.1" a page that can be accessed without authentication and Authenticated.

I used the anonymous, but here is a token of the Authenticated User Anonymous and not be proper token.

Does anyone have a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the [security](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html):

> Anonymous users are technically authenticated, meaning that the
>   isAuthenticated() method of an anonymous user object will return true.

```
//if you want myPage to be accessible by everyone
security:
    firewalls:
        secured_area:
            pattern:    ^/
            anonymous: ~

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/myPage, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

If you remove the anonymous key, the firewall will always make a user fully authenticate immediately.

Comment: Thanks to your tip, I've solved the problem, important is also the order of the access_list